# Typescript observable The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type

Tags: typescript, rxjs6

The transpiller complains of:

The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.

about this code:

```
import { map } from  'rxjs/operators';

const multiply = num => map(value => value * num);
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't specify the type of `value`, no inference is made for the `T` type parameter of `map`, so `T` gets set to `{}`, which ends up propagating back to `value` and causing the error.  You can fix this by specifying the type of `value`:

```
const multiply = num => map((value: number) => value * num);
```

(You should probably specify the type of `num` too, but that's unrelated to the question.)